# How to create an interface for a CoreData model (NSManagedObject)?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, firebase

I'm trying to migrate from CoreData to FireBase. Hence the need for a shared interface across the app for my model.

I have a FTEvent class...

```
@objc(FTEvent)
public class FTEvent: FTEventBase {

}
```

that inherits from FTEventBase

```
@objc(FTEventBase)
public class FTEventBase: NSManagedObject {

}
```

Now I have a new class called FTRecord, which should share an interface with FTEvent above.

```
class FTRecord  {
    let key: String
    var notes: String
    var rating: Int
    var time: String
    var timestamp: Double
}
```

This is now where the problem begins. I could obviously create a protocol as interface for both FTRecord and FTEvent.

```
protocol IEvent {
    var is_deleted: Bool? { get set }
    var notes: String? { get set }
    var date: Date? { get set }
    var timestamp: Double? { get set }
    var rating: Int? { get set }
}
```

But this becomes very hard since Bool in CoreData is actually a NSNumber. The Date is NSDate.  Because of these type differences, I have no way to create a common interface.

Is there any advice, how I could achieve that?